# CSS transition is not working on a jQuery toggle class

Tags: jquery, css, transition, slide

I've got multiple screens absolutely positioned inside a wrapper with an overflow hidden.

When I click a link inside each screen, jQuery removes the positioning classes of the target, and I want to create a smooth slide transition between screens from one screen to another. The current goes off screen and the next one enters the viewport, sliding from the right or the top (depending on which screen is next).

But the CSS transition doesn't work. It just jumps from one screen to another instead of a smooth transition

Do you know what is wrong here?

Here's the [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fredconv/posxoqmt/).

And the code:

```js
function slideScreens(a,t, e) {
  if(t == 'screen--5'){
  a.addClass('bottom');
   $(".is-visible").removeClass("is-visible");
    $("."+t).addClass("is-visible").removeClass("top");
  } else {
   a.addClass('left');
   $(".is-visible").removeClass("is-visible");
   $("."+t).addClass("is-visible").removeClass("right");
  }
};

$(function() {
 $('.screen a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr('href');
  slideScreens($(this),target, e);
 });
});
```

```css
.wrapper__banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black; }

.screens {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

.screen {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

.screen--1 {
  background: red; }

.screen--2 {
  background: lightblue; }

.screen--3 {
  background: green; }

.screen--4 {
  background: pink; }

.screen--5 {
  background: grey; }

.screen {
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease; }
  .screen.right {
    left: 100%; }
  .screen.left {
    right: 100%; }
  .screen.top {
    bottom: 100%; }
  .screen.bottom {
    top: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<section class='wrapper__banner'>
 <div class='screens'>
  <div class='screen screen--1 is-visible'>
   screen--1
   <a href="screen--2">to screen 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class='screen screen--2 right'>
   screen--2
    <a href="screen--3">to screen 3</a>
    <a href="screen--5">show screen 5</a>
  </div>
  <div class='screen screen--3 right'>
   screen--3
    <a href="screen--4">to screen 4</a>
  </div>
  <div class='screen screen--4 right'>
   screen--4
  </div>
  <div class='screen screen--5 top'>
   screen--5
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'v set `.screen` opacity to 0 and added `.is-visible` class to your stylesheet as below:

```
.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```js
function slideScreens(a,t, e) {
  if(t == 'screen--5'){
  a.addClass('bottom');
   $(".is-visible").removeClass("is-visible");
    $("."+t).addClass("is-visible").removeClass("top");
  } else {
   a.addClass('left');
   $(".is-visible").removeClass("is-visible");
   $("."+t).addClass("is-visible").removeClass("right");
  }
};

$(function() {
 $('.screen a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr('href');
  slideScreens($(this),target, e);
 });
});
```

```css
.wrapper__banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black; }

.screens {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

.screen {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

.screen--1 {
  background: red; }

.screen--2 {
  background: lightblue; }

.screen--3 {
  background: green; }

.screen--4 {
  background: pink; }

.screen--5 {
  background: grey; }

.screen {
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease; }
  .screen.right {
    left: 100%; }
  .screen.left {
    right: 100%; }
  .screen.top {
    bottom: 100%; }
  .screen.bottom {
    top: 100%; }

.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<section class='wrapper__banner'>
   <div class='screens'>
    <div class='screen screen--1 is-visible'>
     screen--1
     <a href="screen--2">to screen 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class='screen screen--2 right'>
     screen--2
      <a href="screen--3">to screen 3</a>
      <a href="screen--5">show screen 5</a>
    </div>
    <div class='screen screen--3 right'>
     screen--3
      <a href="screen--4">to screen 4</a>
    </div>
    <div class='screen screen--4 right'>
     screen--4
    </div>
    <div class='screen screen--5 top'>
     screen--5
    </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hum Ok you animate the opacity here when the class is toggled. 
Event if it s not the desirer effect, i understant that i need to set the default value of what i want to be animated. 

Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to transition between having/not having a left/right/top/bottom CSS property. For a transition to work, it needs a declared and valid property that it can work with from the start, and it also needs to know what value to transition that property to. If you do not define a left/right/top/bottom value, then it defaults to "auto". CSS cannot transition between "auto" and a numerical value.

What I recommend here is using left/right/top/bottom intially on the elements to get them positioned correctly, then you can transition those values. Or, alternatively, you can use CSS transforms. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform (transform: translate3d woudl be your best bet here)

EDIT: here is a working codepen example of what you want: 
http://codepen.io/adrianroworth/pen/KaJrzj

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="screens">
        <div class="screens__screen screens__screen--1 screens__screen--visible" id="screen1">
            <div class="screens__screen-nav">
                <a href="#screen2" class="screens__screen-nav-link">To screen 2</a>
            </div>
            screen 1
        </div>
        <div class="screens__screen screens__screen--2" id="screen2">
            <div class="screens__screen-nav">
                <a href="#screen3" class="screens__screen-nav-link">To screen 3</a>
                <a href="#screen5" class="screens__screen-nav-link">To screen 5</a>
            </div>
            screen 2
        </div>
        <div class="screens__screen screens__screen--3" id="screen3">
            <div class="screens__screen-nav">
                <a href="#screen4" class="screens__screen-nav-link">Screen 4</a>
            </div>
            screen 3
        </div>
        <div class="screens__screen screens__screen--4" id="screen4">
            screen 4
        </div>
        <div class="screens__screen screens__screen--5" id="screen5">
            screen 5
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

-

```
.container {
    height: 400px;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.screens {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2; // just to keep it easy to understand in my head.
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.screens__screen {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3; // just to keep it easy to understand in my head.
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, left 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.screens__screen-nav {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 5px;
}
.screens__screen-nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.screens__screen--1 {
    z-index: 100;
    background: green;
}
.screens__screen--2 {
    z-index: 90;
    background: red;
    left: 100%;
}
.screens__screen--3 {
    z-index: 80;
    background: blue;
    left: 100%;
}
.screens__screen--4 {
    z-index: 70;
    background: yellow;
    left: 100%;
}
.screens__screen--5 {
    z-index: 60;
    background: purple;
    top: -100%;
}
.screens__screen--visible {
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: 200;
}
.screens__screen--done {
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

-

```
$(function() {

    var $screens = $('.screens__screen');

    $('.screens__screen-nav-link').on('click', function screenNavLinkClickAF(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var screenId = $this.attr('href');
        $screens.not($(screenId)).removeClass('screens__screen--visible');
        $(screenId).addClass('screens__screen--visible screens__screen--done');
    });
});
```

Comment: haaa thanks for the hints.

I'll try by adding a default :  
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
on .screen

And see what is the result. 

Thanks

Comment: OK it works partially now .. 
https://jsfiddle.net/fredconv/posxoqmt/2/ 

it works for all the screens except for the screen--5. (this one should come from the top, but it still jumps ..) 
Also .. the target slide-in is working (from the left) but not the slide-out of the current div.  because the class ('left') is not added .. still looking why :D 

Anyway thanks

Comment: i found how to add the classe to the current div : 

https://jsfiddle.net/fredconv/posxoqmt/3/
I ve added a .closest('.screen') after the a var .. 

But it s still doesn't work for the screen--5 .. still looking. If you have any idea ..thanks